# Structure Padding explanation

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, sizeof

I know padding in abc is done as below

```
struct abc {
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
}a;
```

Padding in above structure is

```
struct abc{
    char a;
    pad[3];
    int b;
    char c;
    pad[3];
}a;
```

Please tell how padding is done in struct xyz

```
struct xyz{
  int x;
  char y;
  char z;
}x;
```

where does compiler places y and z? and why?

Comment: This is no totorial site. What is your **specific** problem you did not find by a simple search? What did you find your yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Padding is not something universal in the sense that it is implementation defined: different systems may choose to do it in different ways.